# Can a photo app for Android improve image quality?

Tags: software, image-quality, android, apps, smartphone

Is there an app to post-process the photos (taken by phone's camera) to improve their quality ?

I was told that IPhone makes better photos because of good (built-in) post-processing software. Is there a good 3rd party photo post-processing app for Android?

Comment: A post processing app to improve image quality? I think you may watch too many spy movies.

Comment: Do any Android phones expose the RAW data to apps, or is it just the processes JPEG? Makes a big difference in what is possible!

Comment: @mattdm:  See my answer to [this question](http://photo.stackexchange.com/q/24758/6508).

Comment: I flashed a new custom ROM on my android phone and the crappy camera started giving a bit better photos than before. So I guess at system level, the drivers may have some effect on quality but on App level, it all looks same to me.

Answer (score 4):

IPhones don't make better photos.  They have a decent camera (as far as phone cameras go) but there are other phones with better cameras.  There are tons of options for post-processing on both Android, Windows Phone and iOS that are better than the built in camera apps on any of the phones.  Adobe even makes a mobile version of "Photoshop" though it's really nothing at all like Photoshop.

As far as recommendations of specific mobile applications, I don't do much in the way of processing on my phone as I have yet to find any phone based software that works as well as using a PC.  The Photoshop app might be worth a try, though there are probably better options available cheaper.  I'd recommend looking in the app market for well rated apps that are compatible with your phone.

Comment: Also, editing color without color management means you can't be sure your edits are improvements. (...and phones aren't color managed)

Comment: @Tristan - actually, there are color management options available now, though it requires using particular gallery software that handles applying the color profile.  So while you are pretty effectively correct, it isn't 100% technically correct.